# Some pages, code, and direct links work properly on my local setup but not on the server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a project on Vue.js, but the issue is that some code and direct page links are working on localhost, but on the server, there are some issues. For example, the logout button is not working on some pages. I have placed the logout button on the header, which is the same on all website pages. I don't understand why it's not working on only 1-2 pages on the server while it's working fine locally. Also, when I go to website.com/service/a, it shows a blank page on the server, but it works on desktop. On the server, if I go to the services page, the links on that page work fine, but when I try to open them directly, they don't work. I have already run npm run build, but I still have issues. The console is showing chunk errors, but even after uploading the complete project again, the issues persist.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have implemented [routing](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html) using the History API.

The History API is a means of telling the browser "I am changing the page using JavaScript so that it is the same as if you loaded a whole new page from this URL". The browser then updates its history (so the back button works) and the URL in the address bar without making a new request to the URL.

Your problem is that you haven't set up the server to handle that URL in your production environment so when you go to that URL (instead of using the history API to fake going to it).

(In your development environment the development server will send a bootstrap HTML document for any unknown URL which will load your app and then fill in the gaps with client-side JS.).

You should implement [server side rendering (as per the Vue manual)](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html).

Alternatively, you could use hash routing.